# How to solve 'createMarquee is not defined' error?

Tags: jquery, marquee, news-ticker

I am trying to use this [Simple Marquee plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Text-Scrolling-Simple-Marquee.html) for a news ticker. I have done everything as the documentation. But, still I am getting an error saying, "**Uncaught ReferenceError: createMarquee is not defined**". Why am I getting this error. How to solve this?

```js
$(function (){
  createMarquee();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #4FC2E5;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marquee-sibling {
  padding: 0;
  background: #3BB0D6;
  width: 20%;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.marquee,
*[class^="marquee"] {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
}

.marquee { margin-left: 25%; }

.marquee-content-items {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee-content-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #fff;
}

.marquee-content-items li:after {
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-sibling"> Breaking News </div>
  <div class="marquee">
    <ul class="marquee-content-items">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/conradfeyt/Simple-Marquee/master/js/marquee.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you are using from github is not the same version as in the demo you linked.

Now you need to call the plugin this way:

> $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();

Please note that the HTML and CSS required for this plugin are also changed.

```js
$(function (){
  $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
});
```

```css
.simple-marquee-container *{
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -o-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.simple-marquee-container {
 width: 100%;
 background: grey;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee-sibling {
 padding: 0;
 background: rgb(61, 61, 61);
 width: 20%;
 height: 45px;
 line-height: 42px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2000;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee, .simple-marquee-container *[class^="marquee"] {
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position:absolute;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee{
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee-content-items{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee-content-items li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #fff;
}

.simple-marquee-container .marquee-content-items li:after{
 content: "|";
 margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-marquee-container">
 <div class="marquee-sibling">
  I am here to iritate you
 </div>
 <div class="marquee">
  <ul class="marquee-content-items">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/conradfeyt/Simple-Marquee/master/js/marquee.js"></script>
```